# Android Google map API V2 applied inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have an Activity with A, B fragments inside. Then I have a bunch of C, D, E, F etc. fragments that I could swap with the A and B fragments.

Now in one of the fragments, says F, I want to include a Google map V2.
From the tutorial, it only teaches how to include a Map Fragment inside a activity...
link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

As I cannot open a fragment inside a fragment (i.e. include a map fragment inside my fragment F, errors will be prompted), how should I get over this?

Many Many thanks!!!!!

Comment: got the solution? i have also the same proble

Comment: if you have solution - provide it, please.

Comment: I didn't get a work around on the issue..... I simply just start a new activity with the map inside and added a "back" button for that activity.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Have the map as a View in the Layout, and in Fragment F:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container,
            false);
GoogleMap map = getFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

}
```

**map_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: But this only allow me to view the map once.... in i call the fragment with map again, the app just closes itself...

Comment: Happen same to me, first one open well, next one closes =X